# I messed up the line sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig. How do I fix it?

Tags: homebrew

When trying to download something with brew, I got an message:

```
Error: The following directories are not writable by your user:
/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig

You should change the ownership of these directories to your user.
  sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig

And make sure that your user has write permission.
  chmod u+w /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig
```

I mistakenly thought that I need to replace `$(whoami)` with my name and then I got a warning that zsh: command not found "myname" but asked for a password. I didn't think much before I input the password.

And then I got this after I inputted the password:

```
usage: chown [-fhnv] [-R [-H | -L | -P]] owner[:group] file ...
       chown [-fhnv] [-R [-H | -L | -P]] :group file ...
```

And just after that, I realized that I shouldn't have replaced `$(whoami)`. How do I fix this?

I tried running that line again with correct $(whoami) but nothing happened. Should I be fine to go ahead and run

```
chmod u+w /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig
```

Or try to fix this before I run this next line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This block of text:

```
usage: chown [-fhnv] [-R [-H | -L | -P]] owner[:group] file ...
       chown [-fhnv] [-R [-H | -L | -P]] :group file ...
```

is simply stating how the `chown` command works.

> I tried running that line again with correct $(whoami) but nothing happened.

That's ok, you shouldn't see any output.

You should be ok to run the following command now: `chmod u+w /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig`